# In-App Billing: Is ProductID and SubscriptionID the same?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

I currently design my implementation strategy for possible status updates (from status purchased to status cancelled and so on) in in-app billing which is a real headache, and there is a confusion:

I fetch [getPurchases()](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases) in the app. This gives me `INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA` which contains [Table 6](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) with the following fields:

> autoRenewing, orderId, packageName, productId, purchaseTime,
>   purchaseState, developerPayload, purchaseToken.

I want to send some of these variables to my server (although just purchaseToken seems to be useful), but there is something unclear to me:
On the server side, I want to continuously check if the purchases are valid. I plan to do this with https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get

But this request needs, **packageName, subscriptionId**, and **token**. Token is the **purchaseToken** from **getPurchases()** but is the **subscriptionId** the **productId** from **getPurchases()**?

When you [invoke the manual for creating a product list in Google Play](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-list-setup), you see here at the header of this manual **Adding items one at a time to a product list** at step 4 **Click Create managed product or Create subscription as appropriate.** and there you have to set a **productId** at step 5.

If **productId** == **subscriptionId**, why are there two Google Play Developer API requests then, one for "products", one for "subscriptions", so is a subscription not a product then? See:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get

The first request takes the **productId**, but the second request the **subscriptionId** which I don't have, except, that productId and subscriptionId is the same.
This is very confusing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After almost 5(!) months I finished the whole in-app-billing implementation in my app and on my backend server.
I can confirm now that productId == subscriptionId == sku.